# Can I use .NET 3.5 language features in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: linq, 2007

Can I use .NET 3.5 language features in SharePoint 2007.
I want to use LINQ on an in memory collection (SPListItemCollection for example).
I want to write extension methods.
Can I do this with SharePoint 2007?
I am not expecting to be able to use LINQ to SharePoint or other SharePoint 2010 features just the language features of C# 3.5.
Does the server need special configuration, web.config changes.
I need to target my project that builds my assembly to 3.5 and my project references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use .NET 3.5 with MOSS 2007 development. For configuration, see:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/10/10/enabling-net-3-5-in-sharepoint-2007-sites-the-lazy-way.aspx